# How often should custom exceptions be defined in python?

Tags: python

In trying to eliminate potential race condition in a python module I wrote to monitor some specialized workflows, I learned about python's "easier to ask forgiveness than permission" (EAFP) coding style, and I'm now raising lots of custom exceptions with try/except blocks where I used to use if/thens.

I'm new to python and This EAFP style makes sense logically and seems make my code more robust, but something about this feels way overboard.  Is is bad practice to define one or more exceptions per method?

These custom exceptions tend to be useful only to a single method and, while it feels like a functionally correct solution, it seems like a lot of code to maintain.

Here a sample method for example:

```
class UploadTimeoutFileMissing(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.parameter = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.parameter)

class UploadTimeoutTooSlow(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.parameter = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.parameter)

def check_upload(file, timeout_seconds, max_age_seconds, min_age_seconds):

    timeout = time.time() + timeout_seconds

    ## Check until file found or timeout
    while (time.time() < timeout):

        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            filetime = os.path.getmtime(file)
            filesize = os.path.getsize(file)
        except OSError:
            print "File not found %s" % file
            continue

        fileage = time.time() - filetime

        ## Make sure file isn't pre-existing
        if fileage > max_age_seconds:
            print "File too old %s" % file
            continue

        ## Make sure file isn't still uploading
        elif fileage <= min_age_seconds:
            print "File too new %s" % file
            continue

        return(filetime, filesize)

    ## Timeout
    try:
        filetime
        filesize
        raise UploadTimeoutTooSlow("File still uploading")

    except NameError:
        raise UploadTimeoutFileMissing("File not sent")
```

Comment: The Python Standard Library has ~200k lines of code and gets by with 165 exceptions - sure you need your own? (I pulled the numbers from a talk called "[Stop writing classes](http://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0)")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> define one or more exceptions per method

If you mean that the exception is actually defined per method as in "within the method body", then **yes**. That is bad practice. This is true also if you define two exceptions that would relate to the same error but you create two because two different methods raise them.

If you ask whether it is bad practice to **raise** more than one exception per method, then **no**, that is good practice. And if the errors are not of the same category, it's perfectly ok to define several exceptions per module.

In general, for **larger modules** you will define more than one exception. If you would work on some arithmetic library and you would define a ZeroDivisionError and an OverflowError (if they weren't already defined in python, because you can of course re-use those) that would be perfectly fine.

Comment: he may have meant the number (count) of exceptions in relation with the count of methods. ie. 3 methods => 4 exceptions, 8 methods => 11 exceptions

Comment: he may have meant the number (count) of exception definitions within the module in relation with the count of their uses. In other words, if it is okay to define `UploadTimeoutTooSlow` and `UploadTimeoutFileMissing` and use both of them once in the module. I would recommend to define a slightly more general `UploadTimeout` exception and pass the specific strings as arguments of that exception.

Answer (score 4):

> Is is bad practice to define one or more exceptions per method?

Yes.

One per module is more typical.  It depends, of course, on the detailed semantics.  The question boils down to this:  "What will you really try to catch?"

If you're never going to use `except ThisVeryDetailedException:` in your code, then your very detailed exception isn't very helpful.

If you can do this: `except Error as e: if e.some_special_case` for the very few times it matters, then you can easily simplify to one exception per module and handle your special cases as attributes of the exception rather than different types of exceptions.

The common suggestions (one per module, named `Error`) means that your code will often look like this.

```
try: 
    something
except some_module.Error as e:
    carry on
```

This gives you a nice naming convention: `module.Error`.  This covers numerous sins.

---

On an unrelated note, if you think you've got "potential race condition" you should probably redesign things correctly or stop trying to use threads or switch to multiprocessing.  If you use multiprocessing, you'll find that it's very easy to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to weigh in on this because custom exceptions are dear to my heart. I'll explain my circumstances and the reader can weigh them against their own.

I'm the pipeline architect for a visual effects company - most of what I do involves developing what I call the "Facility API" - it's a system of a great many modules which handle everything from locating things on the filesystem, managing module/tool/project configuration, to handling datatypes from various CG applications to enable collaboration.

I go to great lengths to try to ensure that Python's built-in exceptions never bubble up. Since our developers will be relying on an ecosystem of existing modules to build their own tools on top of, having the API let a generic `IOError` escape is counterproductive - especially since the calling routine might not even be aware that it's reading the filesystem (abstraction is a beautiful thing). If the underlying module is unable to express something meaningful about that error, more work needs to be done.

My approach to solving this is to create a facility exception class from which all other facility exceptions are derived. There are subclasses of that for specific types of task or specific host applications - which allows me to customize error handling (for instance, exceptions raised in Maya will launch a UI to aid in troubleshooting since the usual exception would be raised in an inconspicuous console and would often be missed).

All sorts of reporting is built into the facility exception class - exceptions don't appear to a user without also being reported internally. For a range of exceptions, I get an IM any time one is raised. Others simply report quietly into a database that I can query for recent (daily or weekly) reports. Each links to EXTENSIVE data captured from the user session - typically including a screenshot, stack trace, system configuration, and a whole lot more. This means I can effectively troubleshoot problems before they're reported - and have more information at my fingertips than most users are likely able to provide.

Very fine gradations in purpose are discouraged - the exceptions accept passed values (sometimes even a dictionary instead of a string, if we want to provide plenty of data for troubleshooting) to provide with their formatted output.

So no - I don't think defining an exception or two per module is unreasonable - but they need to be meaningful and add something to the project. If you're just wrapping an `IOError` to `raise MyIOError("I got an IO error!")`, then you may want to rethink that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary to have an extremely specific exception for every possible scenario.  A single `UploadTimeoutError` would probably be fine, and you can just customize the exception string - that's what the strings are for, after all.  Note how python doesn't have a separate exception for every possible type of syntax error, just a general `SyntaxError`.

Also - is it actually necessary to define the `__init__` and `__str__` methods for each of your custom exceptions?  As far as I can tell, if you're not implementing any unusual behavior, you don't need to add any code:

```
>>> class MyException(Exception): pass
... 
>>> raise MyException("oops!")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
MyException: oops!    
>>> str(MyException("oops!"))
'oops!'
```